# Is it possible to install QEMU with msysGit?

Tags: mingw, windows-8.1, msysgit, qemu, git-bash

`QEMU` is said to be able to be installed with `MinGW`, but is it possible with `msysGit`? I know I could just do it with `Cygwin`, but honestly, I'm much more comfortable with `Git Bash`, not to mention it didn't work when I tried it with `Cygwin` (but that's a separate issue). Also, what do I need to be aware of, if anything, with `QEMU`/`Windows` interaction, and more specifically with Windows 8 64-bit?

So, is it possible, or do I just need to install vanilla `MinGW`?